# Pulling in one edge of a cube. I cant get the right movemen

Tags: mesh, edges

Hello all I am trying to learn some basics to Blender modelling. I want to make a snooker table. Currently I am making the cushions which hang over the edge of the table.

I just want it to be simple so I want the cushion to be just a triangular shape 2 inches high.

I've made the cube fit along the table and all I want to do is move the bottom left edge (from the view in my pic) inwards on itself so that the cube isnt square anymore (eventually i'll make it more detailed something like this:

[image]

I've tried hotkey "G" when in vertex,edge and face select edit mode. But I can't get that darn corner side to pull inwards.

Annoyingly I can do the opposite side, so I could have already made it opposite and then rotated it, but that makes me think doing it that way would be really annoying if I was trying to make some highly detailed objects (such as robotic infantry, spaceships , etc etc for games) in the future.

Here is the screenshot that I hope shows what I mean. I'm really new to Blender and so I hope im just missing something simple. Many thanks

[image]

NOTE: To be very clear of what im trying to achieve exactly here... The highlighted edge in my screenshot needs to be pulled on Y-axis so that the bottom face is smaller on Y. BUT the bottom-right corner needs to stay exactly where it is (ie. at right-angle with the rest of the cushion). Hope that makes sense. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure to understand, are you trying to do this?

[image]

I used the visual transform widget to make it easy to understand, but you could do the same using <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> and grabbing to the desired amount that edge over Y.

Comment: thats wierd!?? I have been using G and Y with the edge selected. But when i did it the Edge itself (just a black line) moves away from the mesh and appears to have no effect. Thanks for the GIF showing me tho, atleast this proves to my brain that it is possible to do the way I was expecting.

Comment: lol i started a new project and it worked straight away. Have no clue why it wasnt working before . thanks again